# How to logoff from Microsoft Oauth login account?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I have an mvc4 web application and I have implemented microsoft external login in it. but my logout is not working. for logout I used-

```
 WebSecurity.Logout();
 Session.RemoveAll();
 return RedirectToAction("UserLogin");
```

but It is not working. After logging out when I again click my login button it automatically logs in with previous account.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying my Solution i would like to `suggest you` to Just open **MVC Application with default Template** and check how the default functionality is working for `Login` and `Logout`.

I'm Sure you can easily identify your mistake and you will get solution.

Also Try the Below given solution which is im using in my project and currently its working fine to me.

**In Your App_Start: Create a Class Like Below**

```
public class AuthorizeUser : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return false;
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

**In Your Controller :**

```
    [AuthorizeUser]
    public class UserController : BaseController<Users>
    {
       [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public ActionResult LogOff()
       {
           FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
           return RedirectToAction("UserLogin");
       }
    }
```

**In Your Fillter Config :**

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeUser()); // Register Authorize User
    }
}
```

**Verify it in Global.ascx:**

```
        protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                if (authTicket.UserData == "OAuth") return;
            }
        }
```

**In Your View :**

```
<span>
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutform" }))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutform').submit()">Logoff</a>   
}
</span>
```

**Your Login Action Result should have `AllowAnonymous` Access in your Conroller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UserLogin(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) // Model is optional But return URL is required
    {
         // Do Stuff
    }
```

**First / Index Calling of `Login` Form :**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View(new LoginViewModel());
}
```

**Return Url is Must in Controller:**

```
    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) return Redirect(returnUrl);
        else return RedirectToAction("UserLogin");
    }
```

**Note : Add this in all the Controllers :**

```
[AuthorizeUser]
```

Good Luck :)